# How to customize sorting of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, bash, shell

Have a list:

```
list = ['UUU', 'UCU', 'UAU', 'UGU', 'AAC', 'AAG', 'AGC', 'GGG']
```

And I want to order them considering that A = 1, G = 2, C = 3, and U = 4.

How to do this in python or linux / bash shell using or sort?

When I use or sort C comes before G. How to solve this?

Comment: What would be the expected output for this?

Comment: 'AAG', 'AAC', 'AGC', 'GGG', 'UAU', 'UGU', 'UCU', 'UUU'

Answer (score 4):

This would be a good use of python's [`translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) which is very efficient for this sort of thing:

```
l = ['UUU', 'UCU', 'UAU', 'UGU', 'AAC', 'AAG', 'AGC', 'GGG']

trans = str.maketrans({'A':'1', 'G':'2', 'C':'3', 'U':'4'})

sorted(l, key=lambda x: x.translate(trans))

# ['AAG', 'AAC', 'AGC', 'GGG', 'UAU', 'UGU', 'UCU', 'UUU']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
def transfomer_fn(s):
  tmap = {'A': '1', G: '2', C: '3', U:'4'}
  res = ''
  for x in s:
    res += tmap[x]
  return res

sorted_list = sorted(list, key=lambda x: transformer_fn(x))
```

Comment: Does it work for data that is inside a file? Just use the function?

Comment: You have to provide the `tmap` and the `list` in the above setup. Rest should work seamlessly